# head phone wire strengthening part sheared off

Tags: headphones

the protector of the 3.5 mm pin which is designed to bend slight amount, has sheared off. The spring hack seemed to work for few days. It held the pin cover firmly. but unfortunately in the train the spring with wire got pulled ,that time the spring's sharp edge removed the covering part. Thus I cam conclude that the spring hack failed.

the headphone functions properly. but I don't want to lose that headphone yet so some protection is needed.

What can be done to it?[image]

Comment: I already saw that post last week. tried the spring hack but no success. what next?

Also in that post user92592 wrote about overall durability. On the other hand I am particularly talking about the 3.5 mm jack guard.

Comment: the spring hack was posted by robert cartaino

Comment: You didn't put shrink wrap over the spring, which is required for the complete solution.

Comment: @DavidCullen Heatshrink tubing alone works just fine. Can use two layers, one piece shorter than the other to get graded amount of flex.

Comment: @nocomprende: I'm sure it does. My comment was to point out that the OP did not fully implement the solution. [Robert Cartaino](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/80/robert-cartaino)'s answer starts out with shrink wrap and adds a spring as an improvement. The OP started out with a spring and ended in failure.

Comment: @DavidCullen I've never seen the spring idea before. It should help prevent *crushing*, but I don't think it would prevent bending to any great degree. Springs are built to stand compression, not bending. From the photo, the spring would have to snugly attach to the entire plug body to be strong enough. **A spring would not likely help with *pulling* either, which is what he said happened.** Shrink tube would. So the spring does not do much to help, except for mild crush stress. (The cord would be ruined by that anyway.) Sennheiser headphones have steel core wire, you could strangle on that!

Comment: It turn out that I didn't had key ingredient the shrink wrap material at hand at that moment. If I apply it now then will it be okay? or should I just replace the plug instead?

Comment: @nocomprende: The spring is used to distribute the force of a bend along the length of the spring. **However, this only works if the spring is covered by shrink wrap.**

Comment: @Fennekin: I have soldering tools and headphone plugs, so I would replace the plug. If you can replace the plug, I would recommend that. Afterward, you can reinforce the new plug with a spring and shrink wrap.

Comment: @DavidCullen might want to slide the spring and possibly shrink *tubing* on before you solder the new plug on, if the plug is larger than the spring or tubing. You could spiral the spring on afterwards, but the end of it might cut into the cable insulation. (Everyone assembles a PL-259 without putting the barrel on first at least *once*.)

Comment: @nocomprende: I think you should direct your tips on the order of operations to [Fennekin](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/2186/fennekin).